# Too many results in a loop for Project Euler #145

Tags: go

I am trying to create a solution for [Project Euler #145](https://projecteuler.net/problem=145). I am writing in Go. When I run my program I get a result of 125. The expected result is 120. I have 2 different ways I have tried to write the code but both come up with the same answer. Any help pointing out my error would be appreciated.

[Code option #1](https://play.golang.org/p/0jCiwMK1i8) using strings:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

//checks to see if all the digits in the number are odd
func is_Odd(sum int) bool {
    intString := strconv.Itoa(sum)

    for x := len(intString); x > 0; x-- {
        newString := intString[x-1]
        if newString%2 == 0 {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

//reverse the number passed
func reverse_int(value int) int {

    intString := strconv.Itoa(value)

    newString := ""

    for x := len(intString); x > 0; x-- {
        newString += string(intString[x-1])
    }

    newInt, err := strconv.Atoi(newString)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error converting string to int")
    }

    return newInt
}

//adds 2 int's passed to it and returns an int
func add(x int, y int) int {
    return x + y
}

func main() {
    //functions test code
    /*y := 35
      x := reverse_int(y)
      z := add(x,y)
      fmt.Println(is_Odd(z))*/

    counter := 1

    for i := 1; i < 1000; i++ {
        flipped := reverse_int(i)
        sum := add(flipped, i)
        oddCheck := is_Odd(sum)
        if oddCheck {
            fmt.Println(counter, ":", i, "+", flipped, "=", sum)
            counter++
        }
    }
    counter--
    fmt.Println("total = ", counter)

}
```

[Code option #2](https://play.golang.org/p/rlE_NglAjc) using only ints:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var counter int

//breaks down an int number by number and checks to see if
//all the numbers in the int are odd
func is_Odd(n int) bool {

    for n > 0 {
        remainder := n % 10
        if remainder%2 == 0 {
            return false
        }
        n /= 10
    }
    return true
}

//adds 2 int's passed to it and returns an int
func add(x int, y int) int {
    return x + y
}

//reverses the int passed to it and returns an int
func reverse_int(n int) int {
    var new_int int
    for n > 0 {
        remainder := n % 10
        new_int *= 10
        new_int += remainder
        n /= 10
    }
    return new_int
}

func main() {
    //functions test code
    /*y := 35
      x := reverse_int(y)
      z := add(x,y)
      fmt.Println(is_Odd(z))*/

    counter = 1

    for i := 1; i < 1000; i++ {
        flipped := reverse_int(i)
        sum := add(flipped, i)
        oddCheck := is_Odd(sum)
        if oddCheck {
            //fmt.Println(counter,":",i,"+",flipped,"=",sum)
            counter++
        }
    }
    counter--
    fmt.Println(counter)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leading zeroes are not allowed in either n or reverse(n) so in `reverse(n int) int` remove  Leading zeroes like so:

```
remainder := n % 10
if first {
    if remainder == 0 {
        return 0
    }
    first = false
}
```

[try this](https://play.golang.org/p/sPQP3vzgII):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

//breaks down an int number by number and checks to see if
//all the numbers in the int are odd
func isOdd(n int) bool {
    if n <= 0 {
        return false
    }
    for n > 0 {
        remainder := n % 10
        if remainder%2 == 0 {
            return false
        }
        n /= 10
    }
    return true
}

//adds 2 int's passed to it and returns an int
func add(x int, y int) int {
    return x + y
}

//reverses the int passed to it and returns an int
func reverse(n int) int {
    first := true
    t := 0
    for n > 0 {
        remainder := n % 10
        if first {
            if remainder == 0 {
                return 0
            }
            first = false
        }
        t *= 10
        t += remainder
        n /= 10
    }
    return t
}

func main() {
    counter := 0
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        flipped := reverse(i)
        if flipped == 0 {
            continue
        }
        sum := add(flipped, i)
        if isOdd(sum) {
            counter++
            //fmt.Println(counter, ":", i, "+", flipped, "=", sum)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(counter)
}
```

output:

```
120
```

Comment: Makes sense I didn't see that I wasn't removing that since it didn't show up when I printed in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

> Some positive integers n have the property that the **sum [ n +
> reverse(n) ] consists entirely of odd (decimal) digits**. For instance,
> 36 + 63 = 99 and 409 + 904 = 1313. We will call such numbers
> reversible; so 36, 63, 409, and 904 are reversible. Leading zeroes are
> not allowed in either n or reverse(n).

**All digits of the sum must all be odd.**

Try this one: https://play.golang.org/p/aUlvKrb9SB

Answer (score 1):

You're ignoring this part of the criteria:

> Leading zeroes are not allowed in either n or reverse(n).

Five of the numbers you count as reversible end in `0`.  (That means their reverse has a leading zero.)  Stop counting those as reversible and you're done.